# Unable to execute a java code in eclipse ide

Tags: java, class, compiler-errors, classnotfoundexception, java.lang.class

**Sample Code:**

```
package pack.java;
import java.util.*;
public class Bye {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    int a=3,b=5;
    System.out.println("The sum is:"+(a+b));
    }
}
```

I am unable to execute any code in the eclipse ide. I am getting an error.
**Error: Could not find or load main class pack.java.Bye
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pack.java.Bye**

Comment: Is your class in the sources folder?

Comment: What's the name of your source file containing the `Bye` class. Is it `Bye.java`?

Answer (score 0):

- The ClassNotFoundException is thrown to indicate that the specified
  class cannot be found in the classpath. You have to check the
  classpath.
- Still if it has not resolved and you are stuck then you can create a
  new workspace and start coding in it.